# MS Access 2007 - controlling UI behaviour after attempt to insert duplicate record

Tags: ms-access

Creating a simple UI using MS Access, hoping to do minimal actual coding (actually helping a friend who is not a coder).

Simplified requirement: Single table, primary key is phone number, lots of other non-mandatory fields. Display a form allowing just the phone number to be entered, if a record with that key exists display the full record, if a record with that key does not exist bring up an form allowing the other fields to be entered for this phone number and hence create a new record.

Q1: Any simple way to achieve this kind of function? Example?

We've got some of this going with a standard form, can execute code if insertion fails, but a standard dialogue box is displayed warning about the duplciate key violation.

Q2: How can we trap that attempted insertion, avoid having the dialogue come up?

Comment: The person entering the data has a pile of phone numbers, some are already in the system, some are not. They enter a number, it might already be there, in which case bring up the record, otherwise create a new one and capture the other data. (I know it sounds a little odd, but the scenario does actually make sense.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The advice from Kevin Ross to use VB Code is clearly one approach, and I think is appropropriate if we anticipate less trivial requirements in future. However I'm in a situation where I'm helping someone with zero coding background and hence if possible I'd prefer to let them use simple Macros rather than full-scale VB.

As it happens the functionality I require can be implemented with just Macros, and it depends on the suggestion from iDevelop.

The outline of the solution I used:

Create an *InitialEntry* form with no association to any particular table, it has:

- a data entry field for the telephone number
- a read-only text box where I can display a message
- a button labelled *Add*
- a button labelled *Show*

I write three macros:

1. A macro *AlreadyExists* that displays a message saying "We already that one"
2. A macro *NewEntry* that opens a data entry form for my table, in Add mode, and which copies the phone number from InitialEntry!TelephoneNumber
3. A macro *TestForExisting* this uses a condition

   ```
    DCount("*","MyTable","[PhoneNumber] = [FormPhoneNumber] " ) > 0
   ```

to control whether to execute AlreadyExists, and a similar test to control whether to call NewEntry.

While this is not as efficient as VB, it does seem to be understandable by a non-coder, so at least we can implement our application.

Comment: Macros suck. It's never a good idea. However, in recent versions of Access, macros have been given error handling and a number of extremely useful functions, so are worth considering. Pre-Access 2007, though, you should avoid macros like the plague. They are a maintenance and documentation nightmare, and have no error recovery at all.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to get your hands dirty and write some code to get this outcome. A starting point would be something like this presto code. Post back if you get stuck on any of the parts.

```
If fCheckIfRecordExists(lYourKey)=True then
    Docmd.OpenForm “frmEditExistingRecord”
Else
    Docmd.OpenForm “frmEnterNewRecord”
End if

Public function fCheckIfRecordExists (lYourKey as Long) as Boolean
‘Code to check if a record exists, simple method is to use dLookup or a count SQL statement with the criteria as the key you are trying to find
End function
```

EDIT:

First things first make a form with 1 text box called txtPhone_number and a command button called cmdSearch.

Next put this bit of code in the module behind the form

```
Public Function fDoes_record_exist(strPhone_number As String) As Boolean
If DCount("Phone_number", "tblYour_table", "Phone_number=" & strPhone_number) > 0 Then
    fDoes_record_exist = True
Else
    fDoes_record_exist = False
End If
End Function
```

Next you need to put some code behind the click event of the command button. This code can be expanded on to check for a valid phone number later if you want

```
If fDoes_record_exist(Me.txtPhone_number) = True Then
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmShow_existing_record"
Else
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmEnter_new_record"
End If
```

That should set you on your way nicely but post back if you run into problems

Comment: Thanks, I'd anticipated that coding like this might be the way, wanted to make sure there was nothing out of the box to do it. Now to go and figure out where we put that code :-)

Comment: Being new to Access I'm not understanding how to apply this solution - when I got to associate a Macro with a form action I get presented with a spreadsheet style data entry panel with separate columnes for actions and conditions. Using Dcount() I've made some progress (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519063/microsoft-access-2007-macro-issue-form-and-database-with-phone-numbers) but perhaps you are suggesting a different approach?

Comment: @djna Hold tight I will brew up a more complete example later on today and edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an overview of the process with Access logic:

You need an *unboud* control labelled Phone in the form header, where user will be able to enter the phone number to search. You need to use the After_Update event of that control to trigger your search. There will be a second Phone control, *bound* this time, in the Detail section of the form for effective data entry/update.

Use the Form_Error event to intercept the error message when user tries to save a duplicate key, in order to display a nice message, and eventually Cancel his changes.